# DNS problems on Mac

Tags: mac, dns, tor

I am running OS X 10.7.5. Recently I installed Vidalia/TOR. All well and good - except now I can only connect with TOR browser (which has its own issues - slow, flash doesn't work). None of my other browsers (Opera, Chrome, Safari) connect at all. They all show error messages saying DNS lookup failed. I've tried messing about with DNS settings but I'm uninitiated and don't want to mess it up completely... Please help a brother out!

Answer (score 0):

To use the tor network, you dns must be configured to use the tor servers.

Check the following:

---

**Check your /etc/hosts file**

it should look like this

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

---

**Check your default DNS server**
System Preferences -> Network -> DNS

There should be between 1 and 3 entries in the left box. They should be slightly greyed out. Your dns server will be different than mine. If there are non greyed out values, remove them from the list by clicking the minus button.

[image]

---

**Check your browsers security settings**

You need to setup a proxy for tor to work. Check that all your browsers have no proxy configured.

**Safari**: Safari matches the same proxy settings in System Preferences -> Network -> Proxies

[image]

---

**Chrome**: Same as Safari

---

**Firefox**: Go to the Advanced Tab, and make sure it is set to "Use system proxy settings"

[image]